# Get data from NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsdictionary

I have two json files which are linked by key country_id (one country - many cities), data from a json file I write in `NSDictionary` s.

question : if i selected one of the countries from first `NSDictionary` (dictionary of countries data) how to show all the data that is bind to selected country_id in other dictionary(dictionary of cities data)?

---

**What i tried?**

I tried to do next:check all key values of second `NSDictionary`(dictionary of cities data) is they equal to selected county_id

```
    //dict3 - dictionary of cities data
  for (int i = 0; i<=[[dict3 valueForKey:@"country_id"] count];i++)
      {
      if ([[[dict3 valueForKey:@"country_id"] objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:appDelegate.idSelectedCountry])
      {
        NSLog(@"object %@",[nameCities objectAtIndex:i]);   //array of cities name
      }}
```

But because my JSON files are quite big this is takes too long to compute.

Comment: i think that this approach is really bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **Core data** for this kind of thing and have there a relation on City and Country entity.  it will be faster and more correct. Look at this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started

**Update**:
If you want for some reasons really use NSDictionary as you do now, you can at least employ blocks. It is little bit faster than loops:

```
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
    [self processKey:key value:obj];
}];
```

Comment: i was afraid that you're tell me this :)

Comment: @anonymous Good luck ;) Here you have a tutorial on how to map JSON to Core data if you need it: http://www.cimgf.com/2011/06/02/saving-json-to-core-data/